# Accessing sms of a symbian os phone

Tags: qt, sms, symbian

Hello guys I am developing the application, which needs to read the sms from Symbian OS nokia phone.
Are their any API in Qt for purpose?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the QMessageManager QT Mobility API fits your needs?

Answer (score 0):

on Symbian this is easily possible, if the Qt API will not be sufficient, use the Symbian OS API directly on forum.nokia wiki/DiBo you will find plenty of examples how to use the SMS API. This is really piece of cake.

BR
STeN